# Extend partition size without unmounting it

Tags: linux-mint, partition

I would like to create an image of a Linux Mint disc.

Then I'd like to copy it to a bigger disc and extend its partition to the full size of the disc.

I have already copied the disc using `WinImage` to another PC, wrote the data on a bigger disc and turned it on.

I have been searching for some mechanism to extend a partition with Linux without success.

With `GParted` it works perfectly, but I would like to do it in a console. I have been trying to do this using `parted`, `GPart` or `lvextend` but I cannot find any option which allows me to extend a partition size without unmounting it.

**EDIT**

Type of file system is `ext4`, which I checked with `parted` command.

Comment: I guess, LVM is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

Extending (but not shrinking) an `ext4` partition works without unmounting it:

Check that the corresponding entry in the partition table has already the target size (for example by using `fdisk`). 
Then it could then be needed to force the OS to reread the partition table  with e.g. `partprobe` from the parted package  (for more option, see https://serverfault.com/questions/36038/reread-partition-table-without-rebooting ).

For the final resizing, call

```
resize2fs /dev/sdXY
```

It should automatically known the new partition size.

Comment: `resize2fs` doesn't seem to work if the partition is mounted, though. So you still need to unmount for that to work :-(